# WCF multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

I would to expose my WCF service on multiple endpoints. 
I don't understand why this error, because each endpoint has unique address.

Do I have to expose mex endpoint for each separate endpoint?

Error is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config. 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
>      at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
  // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IService1
  {
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
  }

  // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
  // You can add XSD files into the project. After building the project, you can directly use the data types defined there, with the namespace "WcfServiceLibrary1.ContractType".
  [DataContract]
  public class CompositeType
  {
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
      get { return boolValue; }
      set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
      get { return stringValue; }
      set { stringValue = value; }
    }
  }
}




    namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
  // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in both code and config file together.
  public class Service1 : IService1
  {
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
      return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
      if (composite == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
      }
      if (composite.BoolValue)
      {
        composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
      }
      return composite;
    }
  }
}
```

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">        
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" name="first" />

        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8734/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service2/"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" name="second" />

        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8735/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service3/"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1" name="third" />



        <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
        <!-- The Metadata Exchange endpoint is used by the service to describe itself to clients. --> 
        <!-- This endpoint does not use a secure binding and should be secured or removed before deployment -->
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8734/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service2/" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8735/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service3/" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Two endpoints (basic and mex) couldn't be on the same address. Add some specific address for one of them (or for both ones). Does it help you?

Comment: I've added 'mex' at the end of each mexHttpBinding, but the error is still here.

Comment: Do you have to put multiple metadata endpoints or this is engough <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

Comment: It works - I have to set base address.

Comment: Can you post your comment as answer, please. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```